# Why isnt my button changing colors on MouseOver?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

So this is my XAML and for some reason it's not changing colors on mouseover, I added the triggers for it and I thought that would do it, when I hover over the button its not doing anything at all, why is that?

```
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Margin="10,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource RoundedButtonStyle}" Width="100" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid>
                <Image IsHitTestVisible="False" Height="15" Width="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="Resources/addButton.png" />
                <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="20,0,0,1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#9e9e9e">Add Product</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Button>

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RoundedButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="#2d2d30" BorderThickness="1" Padding="2">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Same idea, but I don't think its a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not changing because you modified the control template of `Button` to:

```
<Border CornerRadius="5" Background="#2d2d30" BorderThickness="1" Padding="2"
```

Note the hard-coded background color. No matter what you do to the button's `Background` property it won't take effect since its not *used*. If you want to use that property in your template you need a `TemplateBinding`:

```
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
```

Then in the style set the default to your original value.

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#2d2d30"/>
```

Comment: I'm not quite following along, could you please explain it a bit more, would appreciate it alot

Comment: How do I set the default color in Style?

Comment: Again nvm just a simple setter with its value